# Deleting from ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to delete an item from an array list by selecting it from a JList and clicking "Delete".

The code I have so far,

```
buttondeleteContact.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (contactList.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
      people.removeElementAt(contactList.getSelectedIndex());   
      People.remove(contactList.getSelectedIndex());
      System.out.println(People);
    }
  });
```

I know some things are named poorly, but people (lower case p) is the name of my DefaultListModel and People (capital P) is the name of my ArrayList. Basically, I just want to delete a block of 4 lines from an array. So, the position in the array, and the 3 after it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this for an assignment? I personally don't mind if it is. It's just that I have noticed several questions over the last few days pertaining to contact lists and address books and GUIs...

Comment: Are you removing a set of contact objects? Or are you storing all the data for each contact in the arraylist? If so, see BalusC's answer and try to encapsulate the code. It will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 9):

While `List` and `ArrayList` don't have a direct (and accessible) `removeRange()` method, the need for such a method is removed by providing the `subList()` method.

`subList()` provides a view into a part of the original List. The important part to notice is that modifying the returned `List` will also modify the original `List`. So to remove the elements with the indices `index` to `index+3`, you could do this:

```
myList.subList(index, index+4).clear();
```

Note that the second argument of `subList()` is exclusive, so this `subList()` call will return a `List` with a size of 4.

Answer (score 4):

This is an odd requirement. Deleting 3 items after it? How are they related to each other? They must be somehow related to each other. It sounds like that you have a contact list which looks like this:

```
List<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
contacts.add("John Doe");
contacts.add("Main street 1"); // His street.
contacts.add("New York"); // His city.
contacts.add("555 123 456 789"); // His phone.
// etc..
```

Is this true? Then you should really consider grouping the related elements into another real-world representing object. You could create a Javabean class `Contact` which look like this:

```
public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String street;
    private String city; // You could consider another Address class for street and city as well.
    private String phone;
    // Add/generate getters and setters.

    public Contact() {
        // Keep default constructor alive.
    }

    public Contact(String name, String street, String city, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

This way you just end up with

```
List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
contacts.add(new Contact("John Doe", "Main Street 1", "New York", "555 123 456 789"));
// etc..
```

so that you can just remove a single *real* `Contact` by index.

You could even make it a property of `People`:

```
public class People {
    private List<Contact> contacts;
    // +getter +setter
}
```

Try to think OO.

Answer (score 1):

Joachim's answer gives a good way of removing directly from an `ArrayList`, but I suspect you really want to remove the range directly from the model. `DefaultListModel` has a `removeRange` method:

```
int index = contactList.getSelectedIndex();
people.removeRange(index, index + 4);
```

I would expect that to have the right behaviour, removing the items from the underlying list as well. Assuming that's the case, that would be the best way of doing it I suspect. Then again, I don't know Swing very well :)

Comment: haha.....the names caused me a lot of pain before i realised my mistake :)
but yeah, eclipse doesn't seem to like removeRange. I get the error "The method removeRange(int, int) from the type ArrayList<String> is not visible"

Comment: Instead of removing item 4 4 times, sometimes it is easier to understand if you remove backwards; items 7, 6, 5, 4.

Comment: @rsp: I think I would personally find that harder to understand. It's more efficient, mind you :)

Comment: In Java it's `people.subList(index, index+4).clear()`. The `subList()` method make dedicated methods that act only on a selected range unnecessary.

Comment: @Joachim: Good spot. Had entirely forgotten about sublists. Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
people.subList(index, index+4).clear()
```